# How to prevent servlet to create new session when recieves get request?

Tags: java, api, http, session, servlets

I have a part in my servlet, that creates a new session with an API. Since it's in the doGet function, everytime when the servlet receives a get request, it also creates a new session.

I will create new session only when the first get request arrives.

Answer (score 0):

Servelet does not create new session on each request unless you have added some custom code to create new session on each request. You can check the session as below,

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
String sessionId = session.getId();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that when you say "creates a new session with an API" you are calling a 3rd party API in your Servlet, and complementing Code_Mode's answer, you should verify if the session in your servlet was just created before calling this 3rd party API.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
if (session.isNew()) {
    // Do your API thing here
}
```

If there is an existing session and this session is not new, that means is not the first time the doGet method is invoked.

Cheers!